# Lang’s proof of the Zassenhaus Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, proof-explanation

In Serge Lang’s *Algebra*, the following proof of the Butterfly (Zassenhaus) Lemma is given:

> **Lemma 3.3. (Butterfly Lemma.)** (Zassenhaus) Let $U, V$ be subgroups of a group. Let $u, v$ be normal subgroups of $U$ and $V$, respectively. Then
> $$
> \begin{array}{l}
> u(U \cap v) \quad \text { is normal in } \quad u(U \cap V) \\
> (u \cap V) v \quad \text { is normal in }(U \cap V) v
> \end{array}
> $$
> and the factor groups are isomorphic, i.e.
> $$
> u(U \cap V) / u(U \cap v) \approx(U \cap V) v /(u \cap V) v
> $$
> *Proof*. The combination of groups and factor groups becomes clear if one visualizes the following diagram of subgroups (which gives its name to the lemma):
>
> [image: Butterfly diagram]
>
> In this diagram, we are given $U, u, V, v .$ All the other points in the diagram correspond to certain groups which can be determined as follows. The intersection of two line segments going downwards represents the intersection of groups. Two lines going upwards meet in a point which represents the product of two subgroups (i.e. the smallest subgroup containing both of them).
>
> We consider the two parallelograms representing the wings of the butterfly, and we shall give isomorphisms of the factor groups as follows:
> $$
> \frac{u(U \cap V)}{u(U \cap v)} \approx \frac{U \cap V}{(u \cap V)(U \cap v)} \approx \frac{(U \cap V) v}{(u \cap V) v}
> $$
> In fact, the vertical side common to both parallelograms has $U \cap V$ as its top end point, and $(u \cap V)(U \cap v)$ as its bottom end point. We have an isomorphism
> $$
> (U \cap V) /(u \cap V)(U \cap v) \approx u(U \cap V) / u(U \cap v)
> $$
> This is obtained from the isomorphism theorem
> $$
> H /(H \cap N) \approx H N / N
> $$
> by setting $H=U \cap V$ and $N=u(U \cap v)$. This gives us the isomorphism on the left. By symmetry we obtain the corresponding isomorphism on the right, which proves the Butterfly lemma.

I understand most of this proof, however there is one point that I can’t seem to decipher. Lang uses the Second Isomorphism Theorem which requires $H$ to be contained in the normalizer of $N$. I do not understand why $H$=$U$$\cap$$V$ is contained in the normalizer of $N$=$u$($U$$\cap$$v$).
This is probably a simple manipulation problem, but I don’t see why this is true.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Comment: Thank you, @ahulpke, for that substantial edit.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $v\triangleleft V$, so $U\cap v\triangleleft U\cap V$. Thus, $U\cap V$ normalizes $U\cap v$.

Also, since $u\triangleleft U$, then $U$ normalizes $u$, and therefore $U\cap V\leq U$ also normalizes $u$.

Thus, $U\cap V$ normalizes both $u$ and $U\cap v$, hence it normalizes $u(U\cap v)=N$.